# How to load external data into the view asynchronously

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a Rails 3.2 app I have a view that is pulling in information from an external API. On slow connections, this severely reduces the page load time and affects user experience.

How can I move this into an asynchronous process so that the rest of the page loads, and the external information is rendered later once it has been fetched and is available.

The external data is large and complex and I don't think is suitable to cache in the database or in a variable.

I'm aware of delayedjob and similar gems, but these seem more suited to queuing database methods rather than in the view.

What other options are available to me?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a large data set is perfectly suitable for caching on your local server.

Keep in mind, a long request is going to lock your Rails process/thread and and can't serve any other requests while waiting for your API call to finish.

That said, you can always trigger an Ajax request to occur once the rest of the page loads.

Comment: Thanks @cpuguy83, an Ajax request sounds like the right way to go. Can you recommend any examples or tutorials explaining how to set this up